# Sentry and Android 28 SDK compileSdkVersion 28

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, sentry

I have the next problem. I need add sentry to my android application. But when I make build I got this:

```
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
        at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:144)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: org.slf4j.event.EventConstants
        at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:87)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:131)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: org.slf4j.event.EventConstants
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:64)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$0(ProgramClassCollection.java:25)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:24)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:124)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:123)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:86)
        at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:40)
        at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:83)
        ... 49 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Here my dependencies:

```
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation project(':android_util_fr_drv_ng-release')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation project(path: ':subtotalapi')
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.szagurskii:patternedtextwatcher:0.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.redmadrobot:inputmask:3.4.4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:1.7.10'
//    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.21'

    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

Multidex is enable:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true

    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary true
    }
}
```

Do I think right what this problem is due to incompatibility R8 and D8? What could like resolve this problem? Or maybe exists better analog than sentry? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you find the answer? Share your solution if you've found it.

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Sentry has the worst documentation I've ever seen!!!